# SQLBindParam: setting Null value fails (ODBC)

Tags: c++, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to bind an NULL-Value to a parameter in a sql query but I always get an error *HY009 Invalid argument value* when I execute the statement. That strange behavior only appears when I build in release mode. In debug mode it's working fine. Any ideas?

My Code:

```
SQLRETURN nRet = SQLPrepare(m_hStmt, (SQLTCHAR *)strSQL, SQL_NTS); // returns SQL_SUCCESS
SQLINTEGER cbNumeric = SQL_NULL_DATA;
nRet = SQLBindParameter(m_hStmt, 
                parameterIndex,     
                SQL_PARAM_INPUT,    
                SQL_C_CHAR,         
                SQL_LONGVARCHAR,    
                0,                  
                NULL,               
                NULL,       
                0,                  
                &cbNumeric); // returns SQL_SUCCESS
nRet = SQLExecute(m_hStmt); // returns SQL_NEED_DATA
nRet = _SQLParamDataPutData(nRet); // returns Debug: SQL_SUCCESS, Release: SQL_ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx correctly, you are not allowed to pass a NULL-pointer as `ParameterValuePtr` argument - even if the value is a NULL-Value.

From the comments section in the doc, about the error HY009:

> (DM) The argument ParameterValuePtr was a null pointer, the argument
>   StrLen_or_IndPtr was a null pointer, and the argument InputOutputType
>   was not SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT.

Does it work if you change your code to something like this:

```
SQLRETURN nRet = SQLPrepare(m_hStmt, (SQLTCHAR *)strSQL, SQL_NTS);
SQLCHAR dummy[1];
dummy[0] = '\0';
SQLINTEGER cbNumeric = SQL_NULL_DATA;
nRet = SQLBindParameter(m_hStmt, 
                parameterIndex,     
                SQL_PARAM_INPUT,    
                SQL_C_CHAR,         
                SQL_LONGVARCHAR,    
                0,                  
                NULL,               
                dummy,       
                SQL_NTS,                  
                &cbNumeric); // returns SQL_SUCCESS
nRet = SQLExecute(m_hStmt); // returns SQL_NEED_DATA
nRet = _SQLParamDataPutData(nRet);
```